# Cache replacement policies, implementation of adaptive cache replacement

Tags: java, caching, lru

Can anyone help with Java implementation of Adaptive Cache Replacement algorithm? It's a part of my bachelor's diploma and I have real problem's with understanding of it.
I use the cache implementation in EJB 2.0.

Comment: I've already implemented LRU, and for performance test I need at least one more effective algorithm. I think ARC will be not bad competitor for LRU.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have any useful descriptions of what I should do. In wiki there is very short article, and official article about ARC doesn't contain algorithm. Also, the main goal is to implement Clock-pro, another adaptive algorithm, with less description then ARC

Comment: Try 2Q. It's easier to understand if you've implemented LRU.

Comment: What's the question? What literature have you read? Are you having trouble with the algorithm (if so, I advise you to post a **more precise** question on [cs.se] — something like “After reading <text>, I am confused as to how an adaptive cache replacement algorithm behaves in <some conditions>”), or with the implementation?